# How do I add cookies to my cookie clicker game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-development

I am trying to make the worst cookie clicker game but when you click the "cookie" nothing gets added to the score. (I'm not using pygame btw) Here is the code I'm using:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

points = 100
money = 100
bonus = 100

def click():
    global points
    global money
    global bonus
    points += bonus
    money += points

def update():
    cookies.config(textvariable=cool)
    game.after(100, update)

game = Tk()

cool = tkinter.StringVar()
cool.set(f'Cookies: {money}')

cookies = Label(game, textvariable=cool,font=(14))
cookies.grid(row=0,column=0)
cookie = Button(game,text='\nCookie\n',font=(20),command=click).grid(row=1,column=0)

update()

game.mainloop()
```

I want it to add a cookie everytime you click it. (im not done with this game yet)

Comment: `points` and `money` shouldn't be function parameters, you need to assign to the global variables.

Comment: `def click(): global points ; global money ; # rest`. and later `command=click` (without `(points,money)`)